# Looking for some REGEX help in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
[COLOR=gray]A bunch of text.[/COLOR]
```

And I would like to write a `preg_replace` that removes everything between `"[COLOR=gray]"` and `"[/COLOR]"` -- if it's possible to remove those tags as well, that's great, otherwise I can do a simple replace afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str  = 'dfgdfg[COLOR=gray]A bunch of text.[/COLOR]dfgdfgdfgfg';

$str1 = preg_replace('/\[COLOR=gray\].*\[\/COLOR\]/',"",$str);

echo $str1;
```

OR

if COLOR is not always gray

```
$str  = 'dfgdfg[COLOR=gray]A bunch of text.[/COLOR]dfgdfgdfgfg';

$str1 = preg_replace('/\[COLOR=\w+\].*\[\/COLOR\]/',"",$str);

echo $str1;
```

Comment: This works when I try the example; however, in my live version it's not working. Could that have to do with there being a few carriage returns before the [color] code?

Comment: OK, after looking at it I found that my string is actually:

[COLOR=gray] *return* 
Text.
*return*
[/COLOR] Thank you @Prasanth Bendra.

Comment: I ended up using [\S\s] instead of .